# why are form variables not available in this php code?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form on my PHP page which performs some ajax validation (that's working). Here's a snippet (the live form has more fields than this)

```
    <form name="form" onSubmit="return validate_form();" action="submitform.php" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td width="175">
                <div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b>Requested Vendor TAG:</b> </font></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="VendorTAG" onblur="checktag();" maxlength="8"> <div id="vendtag"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="175">
                <div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b>Contact Name:  </b> </font></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ContactName" maxlength="50">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

When I click the submit button, it loads this code:

```
<php ?
if(trim($VendorTAG) == '')
   {
      die('Vendor TAG cannot be blank');
   }
   else if(trim($ContactName) == '')
   {
      die('Contact Name cannot be blank');
   }
?>
```

(again, there's more of the same, but this illustrates the point)

This all worked perfectly well until the last update from my hoster sometime over christmas, when the form stopped working - but I'm having real difficulty in finding out why..

The server is now running PHP 5.2.11 - am I doing something fundamentally wrong/stupid here?

Comment: We need some 'PHP' Code .. Unless You are asking about HTML/AJAX.

Comment: PHP code missing. PHP upgrade? What did it upgrade from? Were you relying on register_globals before?

Comment: yeah, sorry - code was there on the edit page, but not properly formatted to display. should be there now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP 5.2 They got rid of `register_globals`. It is a security nightmare and should not be used.

Use `$_POST` instead to access Form Elements.

You can find more about `register_globals` here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: thought it might be something like that, but couldn't find the right google foo to unlock the magic ;)

Answer (score 2):

POST vars are accessed like this: `$_POST["varname"]` and not like this: `$varname`. Alternatively, you can also access them through `$_REQUEST` too, but ultimately it's up to you.